# How to Create Custom ZoomIn Button that is Windows Tools Button with Custom Cursor?

Tags: c#, arcgis-engine, .net

I want to create large zoomin Button without toolbarbutton. I created a 'Zoomin Script' on axMapContorol. It worked is fine but I can't set cursor.
My code is as follows:

```
IMapControl3 mapControl = (IMapControl3)FMap.Instance.axMapControl1.Object;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(LargeZoominCursor);
Icon icon = new Icon(ms);
mapControl.MouseIcon = (stdole.IPictureDisp)ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.COMSupport.OLE.GetIPictureDispFromIcon(icon);
mapControl.MousePointer = ESRI.ArcGIS.Controls.esriControlsMousePointer.esriPointerCustom;
```

This code doesn't call errors during the first time only. After checking SelectFeatureTool on ToolbarControl and pushing my custom zoomin botton, the above script doesn't work anymore. The cursor does not change.

The 'SelectFeatureTool' and 'Zoomin' still work with 'SelectFeatureTool' cursor.

How to create change cursor?